# Suspend hangs on 11.10 - need help debugging

Tags: nvidia, suspend, asus, bumblebee

I have an ASUS X53SD laptop I just bought. I deal with a lot of linux development, so I prefer to have Ubuntu running as my primary OS. I have a fresh install of 64bit 11.10 with just "bumblebee" and the latest 'nvidia-current' drivers installed as found in the tutorial here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

The problem is, whenever I shut my laptop lid or suspend manually, the screen dims black and the hard disk light is on but it never turns off. It just hangs. I waited an hour before the laptop battery just went dead hoping it will just do something. I have to force it off and turn it back on - but dmesg is cleared at that point.

I need help debugging the problem. I have a suspicion it has to do with bumblebee. Anyone else have similar problems with ASUS laptops with similar hardware?

Thanks

Here are the specs:

```
Intel Core i7-2670QM (with HD Graphics)
8GB RAM
NVIDIA 610M (2GB DRAM)
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1058 (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 100
04:00.0 USB Controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Comment: Try isolating the problem. I.e. remove bumblebee and nvidia-current, reboot and try suspending again. If the problem occurs again, the problem is likely somewhere else (probably a USB3 port)

Answer (score 0):

before update the bios version i follow the instruction on tihs post: [Suspend/hibernate doesn't work on an Asus laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53372/suspend-hibernate-doesnt-work-on-an-asus-laptop),  and it works!!!

p.s. to meke the script works i needed to modify /etc/default/grub :

```
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Answer (score 0):

With my netbook, workaround that has been successful so far is, unplug power cable (and ethernet if applicable) whenever you turn back on the computer while it's in suspension.

Though the situation (s/w, h/w configurations) is not exactly the same (I agree with @Lekensteyn to isolate the problem first of all), I'm responding because the phenomenon is very similar. I've been successfully resuming my netbook for a month. HTH.

Environment: Ubuntu 11.10, Kernel 3.0.0-16-generic, GNOME 3.2.1, No GPU, 2GB RAM

(@fossfreedom this is what I modified the answer you've deleted, since I think it might have not looked as an answer to you although I included an idea for workaround. Hope this one is a valid "answer" to the thread.)