# can't resume from suspend

Tags: suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suspend/hibernate doesn't work on an Asus Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53372/suspend-hibernate-doesnt-work-on-an-asus-laptop)

I am a newbie to Ubuntu environment. I using ASUS 1225 eee pc netbook, with ubuntu 12.04 version. when I choose suspend, I guess it goes to low power state but when I press any key it doesn't resume. So I had to turn off and again start my system. Kindly tell me how to resume from suspend ? Thank you.

Comment: Pressing the power button on my laptop resumes from suspend.

Comment: @EliahKagan http://askubuntu.com/questions/157735/cant-resume-from-suspend#comment193072_157799 <-- perhaps you missed the OP's comment that it worked?  I've marked as a potential dupe as the OP mentioned that's what they used.

Comment: @LordofTime Yes I did miss that. Thanks! Close-vote cast.