# Asus 1015E Laptop Won't Suspend

Tags: laptop, suspend, asus, hibernate

I'm running 14.04.1 LTS on an Asus 1015E laptop. The computer has not been suspending when I close the laptop. It also doesn't suspend when I choose suspend from the system tools.

While shut, the wireless light remains on, the fan runs, and the computer gets hot.

I've tried the suggestion on this post: [Suspend/hibernate doesn't work on an Asus laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53372/suspend-hibernate-doesnt-work-on-an-asus-laptop)

but it didn't change anything.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model and I have made some progress with this question. At least my machine:
1) Suspended perfectly when using a USB stick installation of the 14.04.1
2) When I upgraded from 12.04 it refuses to suspend from the menu or when I close the lid
3) It won't suspend if I run sudo pm-suspend
4) However, it will suspend if I run as a root "echo mem > /sys/power/state". It also resumes perfectly

I will try to figure out how to get that relatively lower-level suspend to work with higher level tools.

EDITS: **Figured it out, hope this helps**

There is an offending script that makes pm-suspend fail. See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240844

i.e. a thread that I started there to ask help and then ended up answering my own question.

> > > Apologies for answering my own thread: after little digging through the logs (/var/log/pm-suspend.log) found out that /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 was the offending script and removing it solved the problem. For posteriority (for less technical users):
> > >
> > > sudo mv /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 ~
> > >
> > > This moves the file to your home directory. If this does not cure the problem you probably want to move it back to
> > >
> > > sudo mv ~/11_usb_s3 /etc/pm/sleep.d/
>
> Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105...0-wont-suspend

Comment: Add this as answer. They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in Ubuntu 14.10 by replacing 'ehci_hcd' to ehci-pci' in 11_usb_s3. I have ehci-pci folder instead of ehci_hcd.

```
#!/bin/sh
#unbind usb device before enter S3
#bind usb device after resume from S3

case "${1}" in
        suspend | hibernate)
                for i in `lspci -vv | grep "USB controller" | awk '/EHCI/ {print $1}'`
                do
                   echo "0000:$i" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
                done
                ;;
        resume | thaw)
                for i in `lspci -vv | grep "USB controller" | awk '/EHCI/ {print $1}'`
                do
                   echo "0000:$i" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
                done
                ;;
esac
```