# Xubuntu 16.04 can't restart from sleep mode

Tags: suspend

I install Xubuntu 16.04 on an HP-Pavilion G6.

I can go in sleep mode but I can't restart the laptop.

The only way out is to press the on/off buttom and restart the computer.

Seems that many poeple have the same problem.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you installed the amdgpu driver?

Comment: Same PB here. It worked fine under plain ubuntu on the same (desktop) machine (Intel NUC) but now suspend is broken. AND you cannot even tell him to NOT suspend, it does it anyway http://askubuntu.com/questions/788496/how-to-prevent-xubuntu-from-suspend.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am experiencing the same problem and I do not have a solution, however, I do have a work around this.
When you open your laptop lid, bring up a virtual terminal by pressing control, alt, and f1. Then exit the virtual terminal by pressing control, alt, and f7. This will lead you to your normal login screen.
However, after I do this, another bug occurs where the mouse just disappears. Simply repeat the same sequence above by bringing up a virtual terminal and then exiting it to fix this mouse issue. While it may vary depending on your settings, this will take you back to your login screen. Just enter you password and you should be good to go.
If you ever find out how to fix this issue, please comment it because this is the only thing that I have found to solve it.
Edit: For more clarification, I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 and am using an ASUS Zenbook UX305F.

Edit 2: A simpler method, but less secure method for this
In xfce, go into your power manager settings and uncheck the box labelled "Lock screen when system is going for sleep." This allows you to open and close your laptop at will without fail (for me at least). After testing this over the last day or so, my laptop does go to sleep, but I have heard that others do not, so be wary.
However, now anyone can just open your laptop and do whatever they want.

Comment: Neither worked for me.

Comment: I have same problem with UX430UQ and UX510UX.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 but I feel the problem might be the same. The culprit in my case is my graphics driver (I have tried fglrx as well as the open source drivers in vain). I have encountered the same issue where I cannot wake up from suspend (no TTY as well).

If any of the given answers help you, great! or else you should wait till the open source drivers are updated to fix this issue.